# Android - How to clean the database on every build?

Tags: android, database, build

I am in the early stages of making an app, and I am frequently making alterations to the database or code that interacts with it. Because of this, I would like to always do my test runs (not automated - just plain old manual testing on an emulator) with a clean database.

Currently the way I'm achieving this by making sure I've deleted the app before running another test run. This works but is tedious. I was wondering if there is a way to automate this, so that every time I build the app, the database would also be cleaned. Ideally, it should be easy to switch this on/off, because in some instances I do want to keep the old data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `BroadcastReceiver` that wipes the DB when your app is upgraded. Start by adding it to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppUpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

then create a class called `AppUpdateReceiver`:

```
public class AppUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      // Wipe database
    }
  }
}
```

That should wipe the database every time you application is upgraded using a debug APK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio (or building in a different IDE using gradle), perhaps using a gradle task to copy the clean database to your emulator each time would work? Something like below.

```
task pushCleanSb(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') {
    android.adbExe, 'shell', 'push', '<local-clean-database-filepath>, '<remote--database-path'
}
```

It would be easy to add a switch to turn this off when required, e.g. by using a Boolean defined in your grade script. You could also use `rm` shell commands to delete temporary files if your app has created and left any on the device.